# Incredibuild linking

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

i use incredibuild for parallel compiling...
i also need parallel linking but i couldnt manage it for linking.

- do you know is it possible to make it parallel?
- if there is a way, could you tell me?
- if not, do you know any other tools for this purpose?

i have too many projects and i need to link them on seperate machines..

Comment: You can find a bit a information on a slide titled “concurrent linking” in [this presentation](http://www.airs.com/ian/gold-slides.pdf) (PDF, taken from [here](http://www.airs.com/ian/pubs.html)).

Answer (score 2):

Linking is not really suceptible to parallel processing because it is the natural serialisation point in the production of a executable:

- multiple developers can write code in parallel, because code is in many different source files
- compilers can compile code in parallel, because multiple instances of the compiler can take the many source files and produce many object files
- the linker cannot (easily) work in parallel, because it takes many object files and produces a **single** executable

So I think you will be out of luck, certainly for the commonly used linkers such as MS and gcc.

Answer (score 2):

IncrediBuild supports the ability to execute linking in parallel.
Go to Agent Settings->Visual Studio Builds->General->Allow linking steps to run in parallel

Comment: But it says "Allow linking steps to run in parallel **locally**". I'm pretty sure the OP meant that different libs/executables could link on different machines.

Answer (score 1):

You can link two /projects/ in parallel.

You cannot link a single project in parallel. This is because Incredibuild is not a compiler or linker itself - it is just a *coordinator* on top of the existing VS tools. It spins up multiple instances of the compiler for different source files but the VS linker can only be invoked once to link an entire project.

I used Incredibuild for a while but it has some bugs with edge cases (e.g. ActiveX interop wrappers) that caused too much trouble. Add to this that Visual Studio can do multi-threaded compiles anyway makes it not worth the money. (Aside: it is undocumented, but you can do multi-threaded compile in VS2005 by adding /MP C++ project properties.)

Comment: i want to link on parallel more than 20 projects. actually i know that i cant make single project parallel but i need parallel linking for more than one projects. 

i am happy with compiling on parallel machines. there are lots of machines at work and it make it very short for full rebuild. but the problem is on linking. because it does not use other computers..

Comment: Multi threaded build is build multiple projects, if you need more time spent on one project it's not building multiple files in the project at once.  Incredibuild can improve build time over the native.

Comment: @AidanRyan: He probably got confused by the fact that VS will build independent projects in parallel. On the other hand building with /MP still only builds on your local machine so you are still limited by the number of cores and CPU speed on your machine (compiling seems to be largely CPU bound at least for C++). Tools like incredibuild allow you to distribute your build over many machines (on our project this means reducing compile time from 45min to about 2min)

Answer (score 0):

There are some general setting suggestions on [Improving link time with Incredibuild](http://xoreax.helpserve.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=17)

You can also skip linking of static libs where you won't distribute them using [Incredilink](http://www.xoreax.com/webhelp/pages/advanced_incredilink.htm)

We found that addition of a signing post build step would stop incredibuild from working on following projects, adding a comment to post build was supposed to help

```
rem IncrediBuild_AllowOverlap
```

See [IncrediBuild_AllowOverlap doc](http://www.xoreax.com/webhelp/pages/advanced_incredibuild_allowoverlap.htm)